# break line after specified amount of rows perl

Tags: perl

i have a csv file with thousands of rows of data, looks like this
No,
No,
Yes,
No,
No,
No,
No,
No,
No,
No,
No,
No,
Yes, etc

I need to break line every 16th row and output to a new file.  Perl noobie here, please help!

Comment: no perl required; `split -l 16 inputfile outputfileprefix`

Comment: Seems to be related to this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145978/split-a-line-on-every-16th-comma)

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to use the `$.` variable as documented in [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

> `HANDLE->input_line_number( EXPR )`
>
> `$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER`
>
> `$NR`
>
> `$.`
>
> Current line number for the last filehandle accessed.
>
> Each filehandle in Perl counts the number of lines that have been read from it. (Depending on the value of `$/` , Perl's idea of what constitutes a line may not match yours.) When a line is read from a filehandle (via `readline()` or `<>` ), or when `tell()` or `seek()` is called on it, `$.` becomes an alias to the line counter for that filehandle.

Therefore when reading a file, you can determine every 16th line by `if (0 == ($. % 16))`

Answer (score 0):

While, I'd suggest using the `$.` which keeps the current line number, I don't know where your  rows start.

You could keep track of the rows using a counter variable, as long as we know each line starts with yes or no;

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $count = 0;
my $i = 0;
open my $fh,'>', "file$i.txt" or die "$!";

while(my $line = <>){
    chomp $line;
    unless($count%16){
        open ($fh, '>', "file$i.txt") or die "$!";
        $i++;
    }
    $count = ($line =~ /^(yes|no)/i) ? $count+1:$count; 
    print $fh "$line\n";

}
```

usage:

```
perl <script.pl> <inputfile.csv>
```